# Building a react application with Microsoft graph and SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, microsoft-graph, typescript, react-webpart

I’m starting a new job and been tasked with creating a react based application which will be built in SharePoint and retrieve data using Microsoft Graph. I am new to this and am struggling with understanding how to make calls in typescript/the structure of the code.

I’ve Done the hello world tutorials Microsoft graph offers. I prefer to learn by having examples to follow so I wonder if anyone have recommendations on such examples I can look into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow below Microsoft official documentations to use Microsoft Graph in react based SharePoint framework (SPFx) web parts:

1. [Use the MSGraphClient to connect to Microsoft Graph](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/use-msgraph)
2. [Consume the Microsoft Graph in the SharePoint Framework](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/use-aad-tutorial)

---

Also, check below SPFx samples submitted by community members to GitHub repository. Many of these samples uses Microsoft graph resources:

[sp-dev-fx-webparts samples](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples)

Comment: Thank you, ill check those out. Can you direct me to how I can create a client instance that I can use to make graph requests with?

Comment: Check first link in my answer, it explains how to create & use the MS Graph client to make  MS graph requests.

Comment: Yes thank you, I've read that link and I'm able to make for instance a get request. To be more specific I was trying to set up an instance of client so I don't have to write `this.context.msGraphClientFactory.getClient().then((client: MSGraphClient)` every time I want to make a request, but rather use a variable or something I can call instead? Something which translates to what they do here in step 3 (actually they do it in step 2 but I'm not able to follow it): https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-javascript

Comment: You can create a client in constructor of your class component & then use the single client across the lifecycle of that class.

Comment: Do you have a reference to that?

Comment: Check [this example](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/blob/main/samples/react-graph-auto-batching/src/webparts/graphAutoBatching/GraphAutoBatchingWebPart.ts), let me know if it works for you.

Comment: I'm so sorry, I thought I had done that. Very grateful for your help :)

Comment: No problem. Let me know if above example works for you. We can continue our chat in your another question at: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/302378/create-client-instance-for-reuse